# Browser window inside Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

> Just wondering is there any way to open a webpage in new tab inside
>   Visual studio 2010?

I have seen it work with the start up page. It becomes easy to follow online code samples this way then to switch windows again & again =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, I'm sure that you can although my current PC only has VS2008 on it.
Try selecting menu View/Other Windows/Web Browser. Ctrl+w, w

Answer (score 10):

`CTRL + ALT + R` opens a browser window in Visual Studio 2010 for me.

Answer (score 2):

With CTRL+W, W you open a browser windows.
Then ,right clicking on the page or on a link enables you to open a new browser window or to open the link in a new browser window. However i can't find shortcuts for the new operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can open more than one web browser window. Set focus on the current web browser window and goto 'Window' menu option and click 'New window'. It will create a new window of the type which is currently focussed and that's the web browser window.

Comment: I think you were downvoted because the OP was looking to open a browser *inside* VS, while your answer is about opening another window in a browser.

Comment: However you got an up vote from me because this is want I wanted to know. :)